# Unable to Create Multiple User Defined Functions in SQL Server Using System.Data.SqlClient

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to create multiple user defined functions from within the same .sql file. I am using SQL Server and am executing my queries using the `SqlClient` from C#'s `System.Data`.

Contents of the .sql file:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetUserId] (@username VARCHAR(32))
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @userId INT = -1

    SET @userId = (SELECT DISTINCT UserId FROM Users WHERE UserName = @username)

    RETURN @userId
END
GO

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetUserId2] (@username2 VARCHAR(32))
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @userId2 INT = -1

    SET @userId2 = (SELECT DISTINCT UserId FROM Users WHERE UserName = @username2)

    RETURN @userId2
END
```

Here's the error that is thrown when I execute the statement:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@username2".
>   Incorrect syntax near 'END'.'

Any ideas? I'm new to SQL in general but this seems to be a lack of understanding syntax/batching to me.

EDIT: It has come to my attention that 'GO' is part of SQL Server Management Studio, and not the `SqlClient`. If I remove the 'GO' from my .sql file, then I get this error:

> 'CREATE FUNCTION' must be the first statement in a query batch.

How do I separate `CREATE FUNCTION` statements without using 'GO'?

Comment: “GO” is a feature of SSMS, not SqlClient.

Comment: Okay, but if I remove the 'GO', then CREATE FUNCTION will complain about not being in its own batch. How would I put each CREATE FUNCTION statement into its own batch? @RBarryYoung

Comment: @SneakyTactician2, either use separate SQL files or use SMO.

Comment: @DanGuzman what is SMO?

Comment: How would that apply to my situation?

Comment: [SMO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/server-management-objects-smo/overview-smo?view=sql-server-ver15). (Found using <my favorite search engine> on `t sql smo`.)

Comment: You can also just split the string into two, then execute them each on the same connection/session.  That's all the SSMS and/or SMO are doing with GO anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot run multiple batches in a single statement.

I would suggest you to split your TSQL statement using GO and then execute the batches one by one.

```cs
string multipleUDFs = "CREATE FUNCTION... " +
"GO" + 
"CREATE FUNCTION ";
List<string> statementsToExecute = multileUDFs.Split("GO").ToList();

// Create the command 
var command = new SqlCommand(myConnection);

foreach(string sqlcommand in statementsToExecute)
{

// Change the SQL Command and execute
command.CommandText = sqlcommand;
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Below is an example using the [Server Management Objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/server-management-objects-smo/overview-smo?view=sql-server-ver15) (SMO) API with the latest preview [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlManagementObjects/160.1911221.0-preview#). Unlike SqlClient, SMO can run scripts with `GO` batch terminators, similarly to SSMS and SQLCMD.

```
using System.IO;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
//reference latest NuGet preview package https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlManagementObjects/160.1911221.0-preview#
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Integrated Security=SSPI"))
            {
                var serverConnection = new ServerConnection(connection);
                connection.Open();
                var sqlScript = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\temp\ScriptWithGoBatchTerminators.sql");
                serverConnection.ExecuteNonQuery(sqlScript);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Dan Guzman's answer using SMO, you can also split your SQL script text into separate SQL batches and execute each one in turn on the same connection.  That is all that SSMS and SMO do anyway:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Executes a script-like SQL string, using GOs to break it into
    /// seperate batches within the same session
    /// </summary>
    public void ExecSqlScript(string sqlScript, SqlConnection conn)
    {
        // change all line-breaks to LF
        string script = sqlScript.Replace("\r\n", "\n").Replace("\r", "\n");

        // split the script into separate batches using "GO"
        string[] batches = script.Split(new[] { "\nGO\n", "\ngO\n", "\nGo\n", "\ngo\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        // execute each batch on the same connection/session
        foreach(string batch in batches)
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(batch, conn);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
```

*Note: Untested*

Comment: Multi-line comments that include the text `GO` are problematic with this method.

Comment: @DanGuzman True, but only if it's a line with only "GO" and no whitespace.  Indenting the comment is a workaround.  For a complete fix, you'd need to parse the "/*...*/" comments out.  Or use SMO as you indicated :-D

Comment: Side note: Earlier versions of SSMS (2000 or 2005) actually had this same problem.  A GO within a Multi-line comment would still end the batch *and the comment* and then execute the rest of the comment as live SQL.  That caused some bad days at work ...