# Same SQL Query Working in Management Studio but Not Working From Visual Studio

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database

I have a SQL query which creates a database and declares the path of an mdf and its log files. The same query works when I execute it in management studio (I am sure it's the same query I copy paste it from SQL Profiler) but gives a syntax error below:

> incorrect syntax near go.

I have tried using `executeNonQuery`, `ExecuteReader` and `ExecuteScalar` to execute my query but nothing worked. It was giving syntax error due to the lack of newlines in query from my code hence the newline methods in the query. Any help would be appreciated.

Visual Studio code:

```
 string truvamdf = @"C:\Truva\Data\"+VeritabaniAdiTextBox.Text+".mdf";
                string truvaldf = @"C:\Truva\Data\"+VeritabaniAdiTextBox.Text+"_log.ldf";
                string connectionString = (@"" + File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Truva\Ivdexcel\IVDVeritabaniconfig.ini") + "");
                string cmdtext = "" +
                    "USE[master] " + Environment.NewLine + "" +
                    "GO  " + Environment.NewLine + "" +
                    "DECLARE @mdfPath NVARCHAR(max), @ldfPath NVARCHAR(max) , @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX), @instName NVARCHAR(max) = '" + VeritabaniAdiTextBox.Text + "' " + Environment.NewLine + "" +
                    "SELECT @mdfPath = '" + truvamdf + "' " + Environment.NewLine + " " +
                    ",@ldfPath = '" + truvaldf + "'  " + Environment.NewLine + " " +
                    "FROM master.sys.master_files WHERE database_id = 1 " + Environment.NewLine + "" +
                    "SELECT @SQL = " + Environment.NewLine + "" +
                    "'CREATE DATABASE ["+VeritabaniAdiTextBox.Text+ "] " + Environment.NewLine + " " +
                    "CONTAINMENT = NONE " + Environment.NewLine + " " +
                    "ON PRIMARY " + Environment.NewLine + "" +
                    "(NAME = N'''+@instName+''', FILENAME = N'''+@mdfPath+''' , SIZE = 5120KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 1024KB ) " + Environment.NewLine + " " +
                    " LOG ON " + Environment.NewLine + " " +
                    " (NAME = N'''+@instName+'_log'', FILENAME = N'''+@ldfPath+''' , SIZE = 2048KB , MAXSIZE = 2048GB , FILEGROWTH = 10 %)'  "+Environment.NewLine+ " " + Environment.NewLine + "" +

                    "EXECUTE(@SQL) " + Environment.NewLine + " " + Environment.NewLine + "" +
                    " GO ";
               // try
               // {
                    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                    {

                        connection.Open();
                        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdtext, connection);
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


                    }
```

The same SQL query in SSMS:

```
 USE[master] 
GO  
DECLARE @mdfPath NVARCHAR(max), @ldfPath NVARCHAR(max) , @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX), @instName NVARCHAR(max) = 'dddssd' 
SELECT @mdfPath = 'C:\Truva\Data\dddssd.mdf' 
 ,@ldfPath = 'C:\Truva\Data\dddssd_log.ldf'  
 FROM master.sys.master_files WHERE database_id = 1 
SELECT @SQL = 
'CREATE DATABASE [dddssd] 
 CONTAINMENT = NONE 
 ON PRIMARY 
(NAME = N'''+@instName+''', FILENAME = N'''+@mdfPath+''' , SIZE = 5120KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 1024KB ) 
  LOG ON 
  (NAME = N'''+@instName+'_log'', FILENAME = N'''+@ldfPath+''' , SIZE = 2048KB , MAXSIZE = 2048GB , FILEGROWTH = 10 %)'  

EXECUTE(@SQL) 

GO
```

Comment: `GO` is not a T-SQL statement. It's a batch terminator recognized by SQL Server tools like SSMS. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60806335/unable-to-create-multiple-user-defined-functions-in-sql-server-using-system-data).

Comment: Also, what you have looks dangerously open to injectionl especially if the values of the "parameters" are coming from user input.

Answer (score 0):

I just deleted the GO statements from the query and it works now!!